# Node.js Memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak and I have no idea why. it's based on a previous script I made that works fine. All i did was change the names of the variables and change the value of one.

Here's the code that gives me a memory leak.

```
console.log("Mine plugin started.")
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
var vec3 = mineflayer.vec3;
module.exports.inject = inject;

function inject(bot) {

var Mine = false

bot.on('whisper', function (username, message) {
    if (username == bot.username) return;
    if (message == 'mine') {
        Mine = true
        gotoBlo()
}
    if (message == 'stop') {
        Mine = false
}
});

function gotoBlo() {
    if (Mine = true) {
        posBlo = bot.entity.position;
        blockBlo = findBlock('diamond_ore', 8, posBlo);
        if (blockBlo != null) {
        var tempVar = vec3(blockBlo.position.x, blockBlo.position.y, blockBlo.position.z);
        bot.scaffold.to(tempVar)
        setTimeout(gotoBlo,5000)
        }
    }
}

function findBlock(type, size, point) {
    var block = null;
    var shortest = null;
    var x1 = Math.floor(point.x - size);
    var x2 = Math.floor(point.x + size);
    var y1 = Math.floor(point.y - size);
    var y2 = Math.floor(point.y + size);
    var z1 = Math.floor(point.z - size);
    var z2 = Math.floor(point.z + size);
    //bot.chat(x1 + "");

    for (x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
        for (y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
            for (z = z1; z < z2; z++) {

                var cPoint = vec3(x, y, z);
                var cBlock = bot.blockAt(cPoint);
                //bot.chat(cPoint + "");
                if (cBlock) {
                    //bot.chat(cBlock.name);
                    if (cBlock.name == type) {
                        if ((shortest > cPoint.distanceTo(point)) || shortest == null) {
                            shortest = cPoint.distanceTo(point);
                            block = cBlock;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return block;
}
}
```

Here's the code that works fine.

```
console.log("Defuse plugin started.")
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
var vec3 = mineflayer.vec3;
module.exports.inject = inject;

function inject(bot) {

var Disarm = false

bot.on('whisper', function (username, message) {
    if (username == bot.username) return;
    if (message == 'defuse') {
        disarm = true
        gotoTNT()
}
    if (message == 'stop') {
        disarm = false
}
});

function gotoTNT() {
    if (disarm = true) {
        posTNT = bot.entity.position;
        blockTNT = findBlock('tnt', 32, posTNT);
        if (blockTNT != null) {
        var tempVar = vec3(blockTNT.position.x, blockTNT.position.y, blockTNT.position.z);
        bot.scaffold.to(tempVar)
        setTimeout(gotoTNT,5000)
        }
    }
}

function findBlock(type, size, point) {
    var block = null;
    var shortest = null;
    var x1 = Math.floor(point.x - size);
    var x2 = Math.floor(point.x + size);
    var y1 = Math.floor(point.y - size);
    var y2 = Math.floor(point.y + size);
    var z1 = Math.floor(point.z - size);
    var z2 = Math.floor(point.z + size);
    //bot.chat(x1 + "");

    for (x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
        for (y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
            for (z = z1; z < z2; z++) {

                var cPoint = vec3(x, y, z);
                var cBlock = bot.blockAt(cPoint);
                //bot.chat(cPoint + "");
                if (cBlock) {
                    //bot.chat(cBlock.name);
                    if (cBlock.name == type) {
                        if ((shortest > cPoint.distanceTo(point)) || shortest == null) {
                            shortest = cPoint.distanceTo(point);
                            block = cBlock;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return block;
}
}
```

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in this code.  Such as a mismatch of `Disarm` and `disarm`.  And, presumably `if (disarm = true)` should be `if (disarm == true)` because what you have will always be true.  You also have a bunch of implicit globals which is really bad such as `x`, `y` and `z` in your `for` loops.  You should declare all variables with `var` or `let`.

Comment: Please describe exactly how you determined you actually have a memory leak.  It is very common to misdiagnose a leak so it is first important to know whether you actually do have a leak or not.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/fcbf3bfa560a91ca02ba88d644fb4304

Comment: Also, I am new to Javascript, so if this is some stupid mistake, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your screen shot](https://gyazo.com/fcbf3bfa560a91ca02ba88d644fb4304), it just looks like you exceeded the default maxListener count on an `eventEmitter` and thus it gave you a warning indicateing this may be a mistake (it has no way of knowing if it is an actual mistake or not).  If this is an intended behavior, you can just bump up the max limit with `setMaxListeners()` as shown below.

Here's a quote from the [node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) for the `EventEmitter` object.

> emitter.setMaxListeners(n)
>
> By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10
>   listeners are added for a particular event. This is a useful default
>   which helps finding memory leaks. Obviously not all Emitters should be
>   limited to 10. This function allows that to be increased. Set to
>   Infinity (or 0) for unlimited.
>
> Returns emitter, so calls can be chained.

Since the specific code you've included in your question does not directly add any event listeners it's a bit hard for us to know whether your code is doing something it shouldn't here.  The only code that I see that might be worth investigating is `bot.scaffold.to(...)` to see what that does inside the `bot` object.

---

As I mentioned in my comment, there are several other coding errors:

You declare:

```
var Disarm = false
```

Then, you set:

```
disarm = true
```

Those two variables should be the same case.

---

This:

```
if (disarm = true)
```

should be changed to this:

```
if (disarm == true)
```

or even simpler, just:

```
if (disarm)
```

`if (disarm = true)` will assign `disarm = true` and then evaluate the result which will ALWAYS be `true` so the `if` statement is never doing something useful.  You check a conditional for equality with `==` or `===`, not with `=`.

---

Then, your variables `x`, `y` and `z` need to be declared with `var x, y, z` before using them so they are proper local variables, not implicit globals.

---

FYI, you can paste your code into http://jshint.com/ to get some advice on where you may have made some mistakes.

Comment: @Minecheese - Glad it works.  Since it looks like you may be relatively new here, are you aware that if you get your question answered, you can check the green checkmark to the left of the best answer you received and that will indicate to the community that your problem is now solved and it will also earn both you and the person who supplied the answer some reputation points which can earn you more privileges here as you accumulate enough points.